# 'kaptgeneratestubsdebugkotlin' task (current target is 17)

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle, kapt

`'compiledebugjavawithjavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptgeneratestubsdebugkotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same java version.`

I solve this problem like this

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs).configureEach{
kotlinOptions{jvmTarget = "1.8"}
}
```

[configuration line rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae3xD.png)

Comment: What is your answerable programming question?

Answer (score 2):

If you encounter a similar problem you must add this code in build.grade(app)

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs).configureEach{kotlinOptions{jvmTarget = "1.8"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allprojects{
   tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs).configureEach{
    kotlinOptions{
        jvmTarget= JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
  }
}
```